# Resource routing

Tags: php, laravel

so I'm relatively new to laravel and am trying to understand it. So far it has been good but I've been stuck at an error for a while now so any help would be appreciated.

I'm trying to follow along with a youtube tutorial (not sure if links are allowed) and this is what I'm trying to do,
I've a controller called, **CarsController** Inside my controllers file and a model named Car

I've generated the CarsController page by using the --resource flag, so inside my index function I've this code.

```
 public function index()
{
    return view('index'); //Error here, replace with return view (cars.index);
}
```

inside my web.php page for routing I've the following command

```
 use App\Http\Controllers\CarsController; //added by me
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route; //present by default

 Route::resource('/cars', CarsController::class);
```

As far as I understood from the documentation, using resource routing is better as I don't have to write the routes for every function that exists in my controller.

Also, the page I'm trying to view has a directory hierarchy of something like

```
resources > views > cars > index.blade.php
```

That is the file I'm trying to access. Sorry if this is a noob question by I've tried looking at the documentation and googling and don't understand what I'm doing wrong exactly.

Lastly, the error I'm receiving is a basic 404 one when accessing http://127.0.0.1:8000/.
if I try accessing http://127.0.0.1:8000/cars I just get index is not a file are you the blade.php view exists. Also if it matters I've deleted the default welcome page file that laravel includes inside the views folder.

This is my route list through the PHP artisan command,
[image]

Edit: This is the documentation I'm, referring https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#resource-controllers

Edit2: My code for cars/index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section() //error here too, replace with @section('content')
    <div class="m-auto w-4/5 py-24">
        <div class="text-center">
            <h1 class = "text-5xl uppercase bold">
                Cars
            </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Im using tailwind CSS if it matters.

layouts/app.blade.php

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ assset('css/app.css') }}">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body class="bg-gradient-to-r from gray-100 to-gray-200">
    @yield('content')
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It should be `return view('cars.index');`

Comment: i still get a 404 error when doing that, if I try accessing localhost/cars then I get this error,
Too few arguments to function Illuminate\View\Factory::startSection(), 0 passed in C:\Users\myuser\workspace\cars\storage\framework\views\267dcc3e93ce52fcb9040a9a9185662cceb1eab3.php on line 3 and at least 1 expected (View: C:\Users\haris\workspace\cars\resources\views\cars\index.blade.php)

Comment: You get this error on http://127.0.0.1:8000/cars  ?

Comment: yes the error is present on 127.0.0.1:8000/cars,
The documentation I'm referring is this one, https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: Can you update your question with `cars/index.blade.php` code

Comment: sorry for the late reply, but i've tried with that page empty and as well ass with code in it. 
it makes no difference.
Still putting my code there

Comment: did you fix it? if not, then let me know the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your blade located at `resources > views > cars > index.blade.php`,
so your `view()` method will be `view('cars.index')` :

```
public function index()
{
    return view('cars.index');
}
```

Comment: so i did that and repalced it, I changed my route this way too
``Route::resource('/', CarsController::class);`` and still am getting an error which is attached to the original posts comment

Comment: i accepted this as answer as it's well formatted but I would like to add that this didn't fix it for me,
I also did  ``php artisan route:cache`` and ``php artisan route:clear``
and for my web.php my route is ``Route::resource('/', CarsController::class);``

Comment: i would also like to point out I had another error withing my 
>cars/index.blade.php 
Where I forgot to say ``@esection('content')``

Answer (score 0):

Inside your method you can return the view as `return view('cars.index');` where the index is the index.blade.php file inside the cars folder.

Comment: this gives this error, Too few arguments to function Illuminate\View\Factory::startSection(), 0 passed in C:\Users\haris\workspace\cars\storage\framework\views\267dcc3e93ce52fcb9040a9a9185662cceb1eab3.php on line 3 and at least 1 expected (View: C:\Users\haris\workspace\cars\resources\views\cars\index.blade.php)